# Auto background update not working for wordpress 3.7.1

Tags: php, wordpress, auto-update

I'm working locally on a *wordpress 3.7.1* blog.
from the official wordpress's forum i realize that auto update works fine for 3.7.1 and above.

I've add this lines to my *wp-config.php* file and nothing happened!

```
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true);

add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );

add_filter( 'auto_update_core', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'allow_dev_auto_core_updates', '__return_true' );           // Enable development updates 
add_filter( 'allow_minor_auto_core_updates', '__return_true' );         // Enable minor updates
add_filter( 'allow_major_auto_core_updates', '__return_true' );         // Enable major updates
```

To be sure that everything works fine i installed this plug-in ***Background Update Tester*** , and it tells that all is ok :

```
Background Update Tester

Automatic background updates require a number of conditions to be met.

    PASS: Your WordPress install can communicate with WordPress.org securely.
    PASS: No version control systems were detected.
    PASS: Your installation of WordPress doesn’t require FTP credentials to perform updates.
    PASS: All of your WordPress files are writable.

This site is able to apply these updates automatically. Cool!
```

I have tests the same procedure for the version 4.5.3 on a hosted server but it's not working!